# Don't display new text when onClick in Custom ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I custom a `ListView` use `ArrayAdapter`. I have a button as Like ('Hay' in my Language) in each item of `ListView`. When I click into button, it change to Dislike of opposite.

I click on that button, function onClick callback, it does not show change immediately that return to the previous activity and go back it show.

I want when click Button 'Hay' (as Like), 'Hay' change 'Bỏ Hay' (as Dislike) and blue color. But it is immediately! Please help me! Thanks! (Sorry, My English is bad).

[Link image http://dl.dropbox.com/u/14415363/item.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/14415363/item.png)

My code Here:
It is Java - CustonArrayAdapter.

```
public class CustomArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<LoiChucItem>{
Holder holder;
public CustomArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<LoiChucItem> objects)
{
    super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    // holder pattern
    holder = null;
    if (convertView == null)
    {
        holder = new Holder();

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.loichuc_item_listview, null);
        holder.tvContent = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvContent);
        holder.btnLike = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnLike);
        holder.btnMessage = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnMessage);
        holder.btnShare = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnShare);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.tvContent.setText(getItem(position).getContent());
    holder.btnLike = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnLike);
    // Không điền trực tiếp vì không nên để position final.
    final int id = getItem(position).getId();
    final int like = getItem(position).getLike();
    if(like == 1){
        holder.btnLike.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
    } else {
        holder.btnLike.setTextColor(Color.DKGRAY);
    }

    holder.btnLike.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            LoiChucOpenHelper.clickLike(id, like);
            if(like == 1){
                holder.btnLike.setTextColor(Color.DKGRAY);
            } else {
                holder.btnLike.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
            }
            CustomArrayAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    });


    return convertView;
}

class Holder{
    TextView tvContent;
    Button btnLike;
    Button btnMessage;
    Button btnShare;
}
```

}

And here is xml file: item_listview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_margin="10dp"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:background="#ffffff">

<TextView 

    android:id="@+id/tvContent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:text="Content"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    />
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 

    >
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/btnLike"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/rating_good"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:text="Hay"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        />
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/btnMessage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/social_send_now"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:text="Tin nhắn"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        />
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/btnShare"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/social_share"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:text="Chia sẻ"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is ListView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#a0a0a0" >

<ListView
    android:background="#a0a0a0"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="10dp"
    android:scrollbars="none"

    >
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try invalidating your ListView.  Sharing the code for your Activity/Fragment would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Hey it's very simple you can use `ToggleButton` so if you press the Like Button in your language(Hay) then the color of the button Like(Hay) will change its color to green and it willl show dislike 'Bo Hay' Dislike instantly for more please visit the [link](http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-development/create-a-toggle-button/)

just do one thing

```
 <ToggleButton android:text="ToggleButton" android:id="@+id/toggleButton1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textOn="Bo Hay" android:textOff="Hay">
            </ToggleButton>
```

it will definitely work for you .

Comment: But text 'Hay' change to blue text else.

Comment: Yes. 'Hay' change to 'Bo Hay' as blue.